# Polymorphic rails relations in Angularjs application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, polymorphic-associations, angular-resource

Many tutorials cover the simple nesting in Rails model when working with AngularJS.
But I spent almost a week trying to implement polymorphic relations into angular controllers.
I have organization with polymorphic phones, emails, etc. I try to save new Organization.
Here is my controller:

```
    angular.module('GarageCRM').controller 'NewOrganizationsCtrl', ($scope, $location, Organization) ->

  $scope.organization = {}
  $scope.organization.phones_attributes = [{number: null}]

  $scope.create = ->
    Organization.save(
      {}
    , organization:
        title: $scope.organization.title
        description: $scope.organization.description
        phones:
          [number: $scope.phone.number]
  # Success
, (response) ->
    $location.path "/organizations"

  # Error
, (response) ->
)
```

I have 
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones`
in my rails model and 
`params.require(:organization).permit(:id, :title, :description, phones_attributes:[:id, :number])`
 in controller. While saving I have response from console:

> Processing by OrganizationsController#create as JSON   Parameters:
>   {"organization"=>{"title"=>"test212",
>   "phones"=>[{"number"=>"32323"}]}} Unpermitted parameters: phones

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Got any luck with this problem?

Comment: it was answered already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are *permitting* "phones_attributes" in your back-end controller:

```
... phones_attributes:[:id, :number] ...
```

But you are *sending* "phones" in your front-end controller:

```
... phones: [number: $scope.phone.number] ...
```

So you see the "phones" attribute in the JSON the server receives:

```
JSON Parameters: ... "phones"=>[{"number"=>"32323"}] ...
```

And it correctly tells you it isn't permitted:

```
Unpermitted parameters: phones
```

The best way to fix this is to make the front-end controller send "phones_attributes" instead of "phones":

```
    ... phones_attributes: [number: $scope.phone.number] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a strong paramaters issue from rails 4. In the rails controller for organization you should have a method like the follwing

```
private
def org_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(:id, :name, :somethingelse, :photos_attributes[:id, :name, :size ])
end
```

And then in the create method you should:

```
def create
    respond_with Organization.create(org_params)
end
```

Comment: yes, I've mentioned this in my question. Please look on the last paragraph

Comment: Does anybody have more ideas?